# Find how many entries in a string are in another string

Tags: c#, io

If `StringOne` is:

```
Cat
Cat
Bird
Dog
```

How would I get `3` of three if `StringTwo` is

```
Cat
Bird
```

```
public static void FindNumberOfSimilarStrings()
{
    string[] var = StringOne();
    foreach(string line in StringTwo())
    {
        foreach(string entry in var)
        {
            if (input.IndexOf(line, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            instances++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The code above needs to be so that StringTwo can be expanded independently from the program. This means `StringTwo` is actually a file whose data is obtained through this:

```
public static string[] StringTwo()
{
    return File.ReadAllLines(path);
}
```

And `StringOne` like this:

```
public static string[] StringOne()
{
    return Program.textVariable.Split(' ');
}
```

The original string of text is "Cat cat bird dog" and as there is a split function it should be processed like this. I also want this to ignore case.

```
Cat
Cat
Bird
Dog
```

As long as there as a solution that permits this, it's fine.

Comment: Are the end of lines significant? Is `at` something that can be found in the list? What about `bird dog`? What do you mean by _"This has to be done in this specific way."_? Have you considered `string.Equals` rather than `IndexOf`?

Comment: @Flydog57 End of lines as in line breaks are significant. `at` cannot be found in `StringOne` but not `StringTwo`. I'll elaborate on the rest in a post edit. Thanks for your help, I really need this.

Comment: just tell me the result u desire

Comment: @MasoudAndalibi thanks for the offer! The result I would like is to find how many instances of strings in one list can be found in another. More information is in the post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Considering that you only want to know how many instances of a single string from the first collection happens within the second collection of strings.

```
var firstStrArray = new string[] { "Cat", "Cat", "Bird", "Dog" };
var secondStrArray = new string[] { "Cat", "Bird" };

var firstStrArrayGroups = firstStrArray.GroupBy(row => row.Trim()).Select(row => new { row.Key, Count = row.Count() }).ToList();
var secondStrArrayGroups = secondStrArray.GroupBy(row => row.Trim()).Select(row => new { row.Key, Count = row.Count() }).ToList();

foreach (var item in firstStrArrayGroups)
{
    if (!secondStrArrayGroups.Any(row => row.Key.ToLower() == item.Key.ToLower()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"No Instance of => {item.Key} occured in second array.");
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"{secondStrArrayGroups.FirstOrDefault(row => row.Key.ToLower() == item.Key.ToLower()).Count} Instance of => {item.Key} occured in second array.");
}
```

Which result would be :

[image: result]

The last approach showed you how many instances of a string occurred within both collections, apologies for the misunderstanding.

I went a little overboard and added a few details such as `Trim()` and `ToLower()` if they do not match your business, remove them.

Comment: this works great by itself, but when I incorporate my own line separated `StringTwo` and `StringOne`, all of the values in `StringTwo` return one each regardless if it is found in `StringOne` more than that or never. How can I fix this?

Comment: Whoops! forgot to mention you @MasoudAndalibi

Comment: Update: I fixed the issue with items in `StringOne` returning a value, but everything else still returns one even if it's not present in `StringTwo`. What do I do?

Comment: I need to see your data and your code @SketchedGrey

Comment: I am editing my post to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! This helps a lot and will definately be using it.